# Determine the dimension of the smallest subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ that contains vectors $(0, 1, 0, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (6, 4, 2, 0)$ and $(−3, 1, −1, 3)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone please tell me how to approach this?

Determine the dimension of the smallest subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ that contains vectors $(0, 1, 0, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (6, 4, 2, 0)$ and $(−3, 1, −1, 3)$.

Comment: Put the vectors into the rows of a matrix and perform Gaussian elimination on the rows. Next question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1=(0,1,0,1), v_2=(3,4,1,2),v_3=(6,4,2,0),v_4=(-3,1,-1,3).$

We have $v_2+v_4=(0,5,0,5)=5v_1.$ So $v_4=(1/5)v_1-v_2.$

We have $v_3-2v_2=(0,-4,0,-4)=-4v_1.$ So $ v_3=2v_2-4v_1.$

Therefore $v_3$ and $v_4$ belong to  any linear subspace that contains $v_1$ and $v_2.$

Verify that $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent. So the subspace in question is $\{av_1+bv_2: a,b\in \mathbb R\}$ which is $2$-dimensional.